# Watir cannot running correctly when executing cases:

Tags: watir, httpwatch

Please help to have a look for error details in below when running watir for automation test.

Details:
1> watir version : 1.9.2
2> Ruby version: 1.8.7

```
2017-11-14 05:51:06 ERROR [xxx] Failed to create browser object for: IE
2017-11-14 05:51:06 ERROR [xxx] WIN32OLERuntimeError
Attach
    OLE error code:80004005 in HttpWatch.Controller
      Failed to attach to browser. Please check that both HttpWatch entries are enabled in IE's Tools->Manage Addons window and that 'Enable third-party browser extensions' is checked under Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Browsing
    HRESULT error code:0x80020009
      Exception occurred.
```

Note:
httpwatch was installed successfully and enabled it from manage-addon from IE.

IE version is :  9.11.9600.18697

I am confused why this happen and can reproduce 100%, and other test clients with same settings working fine.

Comment: Are you using WATIR 1.9? what? It's very old version, Use the recent version. You can use WATIR-CLASSIC if you go for IE automation.

Comment: yes, I know, it is very old version, but much customized based on 1.9, so may cost much effort to upgrade it.

Comment: I was using Ruby 1.8.7 with WATIR 3.0.0 for a long time, I put a little bit of effort and I succeeded, there is no other way other than to move to adopt all the new features, the new features which are introduced no way comparable to the old versions, so please put some effort to convert into the newer version.

Comment: show us the code that is failing, without seeing the code it is very difficult to tell you what you are doing that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem connecting to HttpWatch in IE rather than directly a Watir problem.

Please check the following:

1. Can you manually open HttpWatch in IE and record log files?
2. There should be 3 entries for HttpWatch in Tools->Manage Add-ons.
   Are all 3 entries enabled?
3. Do you have the latest update to HttpWatch installed from
   https://www.httpwatch.com/download/ ?

If you have any further questions or problems please email support@neumetrix.com

*Answer from Neumetrix, the developer of HttpWatch*